# Is it possible to force the use of the "this" keyword in C++?

Tags: c++

One thing I really dislike in programming is ambiguity with variables names. I'd like to always use the `this` keyword to access class members, but I often forget to use it in some cases, which leads to some inconsistency.

So I'd like to be forced to use the `this` keyword when accessing a class member. Would this be a bad idea? I'm thinking there might be a compiler option for that, but I can't find anything about it. I'm using the g++ compiler.

Comment: Programmers usually solve this by prefixing members with something else, for example `m_`

Comment: @TomásBadan: _Bad_ programmers, sure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit google style guide suggest to use a trail (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Variable_Names)

Comment: @TomásBadan: The Google style guide says a lot of stupid things, like to never ever use exceptions. You are best off completely ignoring it. Why do you take it at face value? Is it because Google is a big, well-known company?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Granted, scattered among the mix are some misguided but ultimately otherwise excellent programmers ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a circular problem. You want the compiler to error out and inform you when you're accessing a class member without prefixing `this->`, so that you cannot be accidentally referring to a local variable or function argument instead … but for that exact same reason, how is the compiler supposed to know that you really intended to access the member? And, if you didn't, how would you access the local variables or function arguments?

C++ is simply not designed this way. Some languages, such as PHP, require that you *must* use `this` to access members and any other access is treated as an attempt to read local-scope variables (whether they exist or not), but C++ does not have that. And there is no compiler switch to make it happen. If this worries you, **avoid re-using the names of variables**!

In short, this is a non-problem that cannot be solved.

Comment: Even without variable name reuse, having this-> enforced in all other cases would be useful to know at a glance what is member or not, and remove the accidental lack of special prefix, especially if merging two code bases or modernizing old code bases that used different code stile